# Running sonar analysis on test code using maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube, analysis

I have a project which uses Maven. I wish to run Sonar on the integration test classes.
I have tried to add the pattern `**/*ITCase.java` in Settings / Exclusions / Test file inclusions (in the Sonar UI that's at localhost:9000). This setting is said to be
"Patterns used to include some test files and only these ones in analysis."
However, the files still are excluded. Any ideas? Has anyone used that setting successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution with Maven.
But using the sonar runner, it is quite simple and works well.

I put a sonar-project.properties file in the src/test/java directory, apart from the `sonar.projectKey`, `sonar.projectName` and `sonar.projectVersion`, these are the settings to use:

```
sonar.sources = .
sonar.binaries = ../../../target/test-classes
sonar.language = java
sonar.sourceEncoding = UTF-8
```

The sonar runner can be run from the test/java directory and the project will appear in the Sonar local webpage at `http://localhost:9000`